# How to temporarily disable PDF bookmarking ?

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

I'm forced to use a third-party document class that somewhat messes up the bookmarking done by `hyperref` (and the `bookmark` package): a spurious bookmark appears for 'author' (so I guess the package implements 'author' using a sectioning macro). Therefore, I would like to be able to disable bookmarking temporarily, in my case before the `\maketitle` command, and reenable it afterwards.

Is this possible using `hyperref`, or the `bookmark` package. (I'm currently using the latter to partly overcome the problem, using `\bookmarksetup{startatroot}`.)

Comment: Please add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @Matthew: Ulrike pre-empted me and at the same time removed the dependence on the third-party document class; a really concise and to the point answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could change bookmarksdepth:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{A}

\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=-2}
\section{B}

\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth}%back to tocdepth

\section{C}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow @ulrike-fischer! It works like a charm! I used it to hide erroneous`LoT`, `LoF` bookmark entries that began appearing after I added both lists' entries to the `ToC`. Thanks!