# IEEE pdf express gives following errors

Tags: fonts

Errors—Fix is required for IEEE Xplore compatibility
The report says:    Which means:
Bookmarks found in document

The document contains bookmarks.
Document contains link annotations

The document contains hypertext links to locations in the document.
Form Fields found in document

The document contains form fields.
Document contains security

Some level of security has been applied to all or part of the PDF. This includes a password.
Font ### is not embedded

The font listed was not embedded
Font ### is not subsetted

The font listed was not subsetted (at 100%)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You have to use LaTeX and typeset your paper using `ieeetran` document class. You are probably trying to upload your own custom PDF. Hence this question is unfortunately off-topic here

Comment: I was using Foxit Reader just to save the file as a different name, and I got the error "The document contains form fields!" in PDF-express.org. Then, when I submitted my original file (that's not saved as another name by Foxit Reader), everything was fine.

Comment: I was using Foxit Reader to "Save file as another name" and I constantly got "The document contains form fields" error message! I just used my original PDF file without "saving as" ... in Foxit Reader.

Answer (score 6):

1. You are probably using package `hyperref`. I think this is what is creating the bookmarks IEEE pdf express complains about. Thus, try removing the `\usepackage{hyperref}`, if any.
2. Regarding the fonts: Here the culprit most likely are graphics, either in eps or pdf format. If you have a graphic with text which does not also contain the font, the font will be missing in the document as well. You have basically two choices here: a) In whatever tool you are using to create the graphics, look for an option to explicitly contain the fonts into the exported graphics. b) Export the text not as text but as curves. If there is no text, no fonts can be missing (ugly solution).
3. For the fonts, you may alternatively try to pipe your paper through ghostscript with some settings like

`gs -q -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dSubsetFonts=true -dCompressFonts=true -dOptimize=true -dPreserveCopyPage=false -dPreserveEPSInfo=false -dPreserveHalftoneInfo=false -dPreserveOPIComments=false -dPreserveOverprintSettings=false -dPreserveSeparation=false -dPreserveDeviceN=false -dMaxBitmap=2147483647 -dDownsampleMonoImages=false -dDownsampleGrayImages=false -dDownsampleColorImages=false -dDetectDuplicateImages=true -dHaveTransparency=true -dFastWebView=false -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dAutoRotatePages=/PageByPage -sOutputFile=myNewPdf.pdf myCurrentPDForPSFile.pspdf -c ".setpdfwrite <</NeverEmbed [ ]>> setdistillerparams"`

where you replace `myNewPdf.pdf` with the file name of the pdf file you want to create (the one that should contain all fonts) and `myCurrentPDForPSFile.pspdf` with the file name of the document you want "repair", which can either be a postscript file (coming from `dvips` after `latex`) or an existing pdf file (from `pdflatex`). This command then should try its best to include all fonts (while also doing some other enhancements). This is for *Linux*, for *Windows* replace *gs* with *gswin32c* or *gswin64c*, depending on what version of ghostscript you have.

4. Regarding the form fields and security: I don't know how you managed to do that with LaTeX. Are you sure you are using LaTeX and not Word or something? (Well, in that case, my points 2. and 3. may still help, but 1. obviously not).

Comment: solution for 1. can also be found here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133303/how-to-remove-bookmarks-from-you-pdf-latex-file