# Prevent PDF bookmark entry

Tags: pdf, bookmarks

How to prevent a bookmark entry in PDF file, for a numbered section included in table of contents?
I wanted to use `\section{test}`, to have a numbered section, and with an entry into TOC; but I'd like to remove the automatic bookmark entry in pdf file.

Answer (score 7):

You can globally turn off bookmarks with `\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}` in the preamble.

To turn it off temporarily, see: [How to temporarily disable PDF bookmarking ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13502/how-to-temporarily-disable-pdf-bookmarking)

Code from there:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{A}

\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=-2}
\section{B}

\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth}%back to tocdepth

\section{C}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, for me I had to set the second command to \hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=1} to make it work again.